# How can I see a list of my newly-created files in git without staging them for commit?

Tags: git, status, staging

When I create a new file in a local git repo, it doesn't show up in the output of `git status` unless I add it via `git add`.  Then it will show up under the files that are staged for commit.

When I do a `git reset`, files that already exist in the remote repo will show up under unstaged files but newly-created ones will not show up at all.

My question is this: Is there a way to show newly-created files in the output of `git status` without staging them for commit?  And if not, is there a "right"--or indeed, any--way of having them show up in the output, without staging them, so I can keep track of which files I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git status -u` is what you need. You can add "all" (`git status -uall`) for extra detail.

The config option is `status.showUntrackedFiles`. So if you want to permanently change what you see, try one of these:

```
git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles normal
git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles all
```

Comment: This worked, after specifying the -u option, the newly-created files showed up in the untracked section, whereas without the option they had not.

Comment: Added note about how to change it permanently, so you don't have to worry about it going forward.